# SQL selecting most recent row inside join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max

I have 2 tables `companies` and `invoices`
I want to select all companies with their most recent invoice price.
I don't seem to get it working.
This is what I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies H INNER JOIN
     invoices V
     ON H.company_id = V.BC_ID
WHERE V.ISCOMMISSIE = 0 AND
      V.DATE = (SELECT MAX(v2.DATE) FROM invoices v2 WHERE v2.BC_ID = V.BC_ID AND v2.ISCOMMISSIE = 0);
```

But the query loads very long and I don't know why.
The structure looks like this:

**companies**

```
company_id | company_name |
   1       |   company 1  |
   2       |   company 2  |
```

**invoices**

```
invoice_id | BC_ID | DATE       | ISCOMMISSIE | price     |
  1        |   2   | 2020-01-01 |      0      |   340,40  |
  2        |   1   | 2020-01-11 |      0      |   240,40  |
  3        |   1   | 2020-01-08 |      0      |   250,30  |
  4        |   2   | 2020-01-18 |      0      |   150,30  |
  5        |   2   | 2020-01-19 |      1      |   150,30  |
```

The `BC_ID` is the same as the `company_id` and `ISCOMMISSIE` should be 0.
I want to select the most recent date.
Does someone have an idea on how to do this and also make the query as fast as possible?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fc3a/1

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: Specify MySQL version. Does it allows LATERAL JOIN?

Comment: @Akina 5.7.28 is the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT H.*, V.*
FROM companies H 
INNER JOIN invoices V ON H.company_id = V.BC_ID
INNER JOIN ( SELECT v2.BC_ID, MAX(v2.DATE) DATE
             FROM invoices v2
             WHERE v2.ISCOMMISSIE = 0
             GROUP BY v2.BC_ID ) v3 ON v.BC_ID = v3.BC_ID 
                                   AND v.DATE = v3.DATE
AND V.ISCOMMISSIE = 0
```

And the index `invoices (ISCOMMISSIE, BC_ID, DATE)` may help...

Comment: I tried this query and it works and also faster :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies H INNER JOIN
     invoices V
     ON H.company_id = V.BC_ID
WHERE V.ISCOMMISSIE = 0 AND
      V.DATE = (SELECT MAX(v2.DATE)
                FROM invoices v2
                WHERE v2.BC_ID = V.BC_ID AND
                      v2.ISCOMMISSIE = 0
               );
```

For performance, you want an index on `invoices(BC_ID, ISCOMMISSIE, DATE)`.

A good alternative is to use window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies H INNER JOIN
     (SELECT V.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BC_ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) as seqnum
      FROM invoices V
      WHERE V.ISCOMMISSIE = 0
     ) V
     ON H.company_id = V.BC_ID
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on columns you need, you might not need to join with companies table. Also it is not needed to test for iscommissie = 0 two times, you can just test it one time in the subquery before joining.

See the query below :

```
SELECT i.*
FROM invoices i
JOIN (
     SELECT i.bc_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
     FROM invoices i
     WHERE iscommissie = 0
     GROUP BY i.bc_id
) i_temp ON i.bc_id = i_temp.bc_id AND i.date = i_temp.max_date
```

[**FIND A DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fa98394617d7b514facfc23273e91634)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the expected output:

```
select * from companies A join (
select * from invoices where (BC_ID,DATE) in(
select BC_ID as BC_ID, MAX(DATE) DATE from invoices where ISCOMMISSIE = 0 group by 
BC_ID
))B on A.company_id=B.BC_ID;
```